# Why is the expectation value of a stochastic integral equal to $\sum_k (\tau_k - t_k)$ where $\tau_k$ denotes the partitioning points?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

In the book "Handbook of Stochastic Methods for Physics" by Crispin and Gardiner, I found the following calculation to show that stochastic integrals [depend on the choice of partitioning points](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349695/why-do-stochastic-integrals-depend-on-the-choice-of-partitioning-points).

First, we define the stochastic integral $\int_{t_0}^t W(t') dW(t')$ as a limit of the partial sums:
\begin{align}
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n W(\tau_i) [W(t_i)-W(t_{t-1})] \, ,
\end{align}
where $\tau_i$ denotes a specific choice of intermediate points.

[image]

Then we can calculate
\begin{align}
\langle S_n \rangle &= \langle \sum_{i=1}^n W(\tau_i) [W(t_i)-W(t_{t-1})] \rangle  \\
 &=\sum_{i=1}^n [\text{min}(\tau_i ,t_i) -\text{min}(\tau_i,t_{i-1}) ] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (\tau_i-t_{i-1}) \, .
\end{align}
*I don't understand the first step here. Why is the expectation value equal to a difference of minima?*

Comment: Independence of increments property.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I understand that $\langle (W(t))^2 \rangle = t$, $\langle W(t) \rangle = 0$,  and $\langle W(t) W(s) \rangle = 0$ for $s \neq t$. However, I fail to see why this implies the second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your second "insight" in the comments $⟨W(t)W(s)⟩=0$ for $s\ne t$ is wrong, I think you were thinking of the independence of increments, $⟨dW(t)dW(s)⟩=0$.

For the paths themselves you get for $t<s$ $$⟨W(t)W(s)⟩=⟨W(t)W(t)⟩+⟨W(t)(W(s)-W(t))⟩=t,$$ as the path on $[0,t]$ is independent of the (incremental) path on $[t,\infty)$. If you do not assume the order of arguments, then $⟨W(t)W(s)⟩=\min(s,t)$ results.

Comment: thanks! The only thing that I now still don't understand is where the equality $⟨W(t)W(s)⟩=⟨W(t)W(t)⟩+⟨W(t)(W(s)-W(t))⟩$ comes from

Comment: This is just the distribution law of multiplication and the linearity of the expectation operator.